# Audio call service provider

Tags: audio, service, sms, call, voip

Does anyone know of an audio call service provider which can make a call to read something to any phone numbers in worldwide?

Our use case is 

1, User register our product on mobile. User may come from any country.

2, User input his phone number and send to our server.

3, Our server will generate 4 digitals as his verification code and send it to the AUDIO CALL SERVICE PROVIDER with his phone number.

4, The AUDIO CALL SERVICE PROVIDER need to call this phone number and read him the verification code. 

5, User input this verification code in our product to accomplish our register process.

We have already had a SMS provider, but there is ported phone numbers issue which may cause losing the verification message, even some telecom carriers may block peer to peer message. So we decide to find a audio call service provider to ensure user can register successfully as the second way.

Please advise the service providers which can satisfy our requirement. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can visit here. -- https://www.speechtotextservice.com/

Hope that you like their services and these providers can able to meet your requirements.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this service?